# Interactivity with OCaml Graphics

Tags: user-interface, events, ocaml, action

Hey guy I'm not much of an OCaml savvy but I have to code a small GUI using the standard Graphics module not lablgtk, I was wondering how it works in Graphics to listen to events such as keypresses and mouse moves, the documentation seems a bit cryptic to me could some give me a small example?

Thanks in advance,
Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses the OCaml Graphics module to display the user's mouse position and key presses in a graphics window:

```
open Graphics
open Printf

(* Displays mouse position and keys pressed in the graphics window,                                                            
   and exits if q is pressed. *)
let rec loop () =
  let e = wait_next_event [Mouse_motion; Key_pressed] in

  let mouse_description = sprintf "Mouse position: %d,%d" e.mouse_x e.mouse_y in
  let key_description = if e.keypressed then sprintf "Key %c was pressed" e.key else "" in

  clear_graph ();
  moveto 0 100; draw_string key_description;
  moveto 0 0; draw_string mouse_description;

  if e.key <> 'q' then loop () else ()

let () =
  open_graph "";
  loop ();
  close_graph ();
```